# Symfony 2. CSRF token is invalid

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a problem with a token form in Symfony2. (2.7.0)

Action:

```
public function registerProcessAction(Request $request){
    $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), new Registration());

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        die('valid');
    }
    else{
        die('invalid');
    }
}
```

And my Form:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'        => 'My\Bundle\Entity\User'
    ));
}
```

When I test the form, always show the same error: "**The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form**". I sure of the input hidden it's in the form. This is the view:

```
<?php
echo $view['form']->start($form);
echo $view['form']->widget($form);
echo $view['form']->end($form);
?>
```

Anyone can help me?

I tested to disable the csrf protection, like this:

Action:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), new Registration(), array('csrf_protection' => false));
```

Form:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'        => 'My\Bundle\Entity\User',
        'csrf_protection'   => false
    ));
}
```

But a different error appears: **This form should not contain extra fields**. Because the hidden input of token, it's in the form yet, and I don't know to remove it.

Thankyou!

Comment: I am not sure, if you are simply missing echo $view['form']->rest($form);

Comment: Running `git bisect` points the finger at the commit in which I upgraded from Symfony 2.7.1 to 2.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom authentication provider, as [described here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html). At some point in the Listener's `handle()` method, I was calling `$request->getSession()->migrate()`, which was causing the problem for me. Removing the call to migrate the session solved the problem.

I wonder if [this was the commit](https://github.com/jakzal/symfony/commit/99b9c78b0034194d8ee27b9917e4d01fac8fb47f) that broke my authentication listener?